# Minimizing $\int_{0}^{1} (1+x^2)f(x)^2 dx$ for $f(f(x)) = x^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, optimization, functional-equations

What is

$$\min_{f\in D} \int_{0}^{1} (1+x^2)f(x)^2\mathrm dx,$$
where $D$ is the collection of all continuous real functions from $[0,1]$ such that in the interval $[0,1]$ we have $f(f(x)) = x^2 $.

Because of all those squares I tried to think of a way to use Cauchy-Schwartz.
I also considered calculus of variations.

But I am not good at either of those and maybe trying to use them is wrong.

Comment: I don't think Cauchy-Schwarz would help because that inequality refers to exponentiation, the superscript here refers to composition. I think some kind of variational method might work, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @AlfredYerger: I think $f^2$ means $f$ squared. If the superscript refers to composition like you say, then you just replace by $f\circ f$ by $x^2$ and you don't have anything to optimize.

Comment: Oh!  misread the title, and then misinterpreted the question because I goofed the title. Sorry!

Comment: What's the source of this problem?

Comment: $f(f(x)) = x^2 \implies f(x)^2 = f(x^2)$ which might be useful. For the obvious solution, $f(x) = x^{\sqrt{2}}$, the integral is $\frac{20}{7}-\frac{12 \sqrt{2}}{7}\approx 0.43$.

Comment: @Beni me. I am the source.  Let me guess , Someone is going to vote close for " missing context " now ? ( yes im annoyed by Some recent closures ).

Comment: @mick: No one's voting to close because a source is missing, but the fact that you are the source and you don't know the solution is not very encouraging. I asked since some problems taken from high profile contests or exercices from advanced books are not easily solved if you don't have some context. Furthermore, if you just made up the problem, it may not even be possible to solve it...

Comment: You know that $f$ is a self-bijection of $[0,1]$, since $f(f(x))=x^2$. Because $f$ is continuous either $f(0)=0, \ f(1)=1$ or $f(0)=1, \ f(1)=0$ and $f$ is monotonic.

In the first case we can compare $f$ with $g(x)= x^{\sqrt(2)}$. If $f$ and $g$ agree on $x_0$ then they also agree on $f(x_0)$, hence also on $f^n(x_0)$. If we are able to find such a $x_0$ in any neighborhood of $1$, then $f$ and $g$ should agree. I did not write it down but those $f^n(x_0)$ should be dense in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Why is there such an $x_0$? Assume not, then there is an $\varepsilon$ such that $f<g$( or $f>g$) on $I=[1-\varepsilon, 1)$, choose $y$ such that $g(y) \in I$, then $f(y)<g(y)$(...) and $f(f(y))<f(g(y))<g(g(y))$(...) which is a contradiction.

Maybe you can do the same thing if $f(0)=1, \ f(1)=0$ and then compare both integrals.

Comment: I just saw that there is no function with $f(0)=1$. Assume there is one, then there is exactly one $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) = (x_0)^{\sqrt{2}}$, but then $f(x_0)$ also satisfies this equation which is a contradiction.

Comment: Trivial. In fact f(x) < x^2.